# Using ListPlot and Joined, how to keep markers in colour but make all joining lines gray?

Tags: plotting

I want to create a `ListPlot` with three sets of data, where the data in each set are joined by a line. This is an example:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, Joined -> {True}]
```

**Question:** How do I keep a unique marker and colour for each of the sets but specify that the joining lines be a single color (gray)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  ListLinePlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
    PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7]], 
  ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic]}]
```

yielding

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Or simply:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic},
  Joined -> {True}] /. {Hue[__] | RGBColor[__], Line[x_]} :> {Gray, Line[x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or as [gpap noted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56580/using-listplot-and-joined-how-to-keep-markers-in-colour-but-make-all-joining-li/56583?noredirect=1#comment162303_56583) `/. Line[a___] :> {Gray, Line[a]}` is enough in that case.

In v10, this can be simplified a bit,

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic},
  Joined -> {True}] /. {_?ColorQ, Line[x_]} :> {Gray, Line[x]}
```

using the new function [`ColorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQ.html). Its specific intent is to make it easier to test if a function is a color or not, as the list of color directives seems to grow daily, or at least every version.

Comment: (+1) the simpler `Line[a___]->{Gray, Line[a]}` also works here.

Comment: @gpap Thanks :) And I rather like to overwrite the colour instead of taking advantage of the fact that it takes the last colour applied :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Hue[__]|RBGColor[__]` doesn't cover all the possible color directives, and you'd be hard pressed to list them all. So, in v10, they added [`ColorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQ.html), which is used like `_?ColorQ`.

Comment: @rcollyer That's a nice function indeed. I'm afraid that listing them all would be quite annoying, I just added `RGBColor` just in case.., by default `Hue` seems to be used anyway. And in any case, gpap method would overwrite the colour.

Comment: `Hue` works in v9, but not in v10 where the default colors are `_RGBColor`. And, they added several new color directives in both v9 and v10, so it would be a right pain to list them all. (Yes, I have done so, and, why no, I did not know about the new function at the time.)

Comment: @rcollyer Then I'm glad that I added `RGBColor` :D Feel free to add the `ColorQ` as a _v10_ version of the answer :)

Comment: added it to yours. No need for a separate answer.

Comment: @rcollyer Great thank you :)

Comment: @Öskå - Thanks for `ColorQ` :)

Comment: @eldo Thank rcollyer not me :P

Comment: @rcollyer Pardon me - reading the sequence of comments is a science in itself.

Comment: @eldo you're welcome. The full list includes 8 color directives, so having the function is _very_ useful.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I can think if is just using `MeshStyle` for the markers and `PlotStyle` for the gray lines:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic}, Joined -> {True}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great answer. :-)

Comment: Clever indeed :) But it doesn't preserve the so pretty colours ;(

Comment: @Öskå Then use `(ColorData[1] /@ {1, 2, 3})` as option-value of `MeshStyle`.

Comment: @halirutan That would totally be fancier indeed ;o) :D I upvoted anyway :)

Comment: @halirutan I'm afraid that this doesn't function with `PlotLegends -> Automatic`. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is that you define your own markers:

```
markers = {
   Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}],
   Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[]}],
   Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}]};


ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}},
 PlotLegends ->
  SwatchLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"A", "B", "C"},
   LegendMarkers -> markers,
   LegendLabel -> "Series",
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &),
   LegendMargins -> 5],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> GrayLevel@0.6,
 PlotMarkers -> Table[{size, 0.05}, {size, markers}]]
```

[image]